# Why is WebBrowser component eating so much ram and how to flush WebBrowser cache

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, browser-cache

I am using a custom text box (read only) that consist of 2 WebBrowser components. It's displaying text with complicated layout (Generating a html code was a simplest option to make such a text viewer).

I am also binding the mousedown event on all components:

```
foreach (HtmlElement html in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
     html.MouseDown += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Scrollback_Clicked);
}
```

this happens after each time where I finish loading of html source. (this is irrelevant but it's the only customization of WebBrowser control I made, just in case it was the reason why it doesn't work)

However, after several hundreds of reloads the text box eats about 2GB of ram, I suspect it's a cache the browsercontrol has implemented, which stores all HtmlDocuments that were generated so far.

Is there a way to disable or flush the cache of WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're probably [leaking event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526829/why-and-how-to-avoid-event-handler-memory-leaks), considering the way you're registering them and then failing to dispose them. That might cause a slight performance problem, but it obviously doesn't explain the consumption of an excessive 2 GB of RAM.

Anyway, the WebBrowser control is based on Internet Explorer, so it's possible it inherits a memory leak from there. You may also be onto something with the caching theory. There is a knowledge base article that discusses precisely this problem and how to solve it: [How to clear the cache when your application hosts a WebBrowser control in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326201).

Basically, it suggests that you manually flush the browser cache using the [WinInet APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383928.aspx). But that seems like a bit of a sledgehammer solution to me. It's solving a local problem using a global solution, which should raise a few red flags.

If I were you, I'd be rethinking my application's design so as to avoid this problem altogether. [RichTextBox controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) don't have any show-stopper memory leaks. :-)

Comment: Hm, but I am using html.MouseDown -= new HtmlElementEventHandler(Scrollback_Clicked); before loading new document, so in fact these should get disposed. It's hard to track what's going on with memory in c# though

Comment: @Petr Oh, then you aren't leaking them. I assumed you'd forgotten to do that. Of course, as you mention, because garbage collection is non-deterministic, that doesn't guarantee that they get disposed right away, but you're doing it correctly and they won't leak. They'll get disposed when more memory is required, forcing a garbage collection.