# Dangling event handlers and memory leaks: which way around?

Tags: c#, events, memory, handler, memory-leaks

I'm not sure if it's OK to do this, but this question has to do with a source which I stumbled upon when doing some research and which I think is incorrect, and I hoped I could discuss this here. On http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls, Chris Farrell states that the following would lead to a memory leak:

```
...
Order newOrder = new Order(“EURUSD”, ...);

newOrder.OnPlaced += OrderPlaced;
m_PendingDeals.Add(newOrder);
...
void OrderPlaced(Order placedOrder)
{
  m_PendingDeals.Remove(placedOrder);
}
```

The following is being stated:

> The OrderPlaced event handler still holds a reference to the Order
>   object from when we subscribed to the OnPlaced event, and that
>   reference will keep the Order object alive even though we have removed
>   it from the collection. It's so easy to make this mistake.

Is this explanation correct?

I would say it is not: as far as I see it, it's the event notifyer that keeps a reference to the event subscribers' function pointer and thus the event subscriber, not the other way around. In this case, it is the Order that keeps a reference to the handling class, and when that Order is removed, it will actually be cleared correctly from memory, assuming there are no other references to that Order. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not an open discussion forum.

Comment: @MikeW This does not appear to be a discussion based question, even though he says "discuss", but a clarification on how events retain references to delegate instances, as he found an article that answers that question in a manner that does not seem logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct - the `Order` class's event holds a reference to the `OrderPlaced` function.  Hence the instance that contains the `OrderPlaced` function that is subscribed cannot be GC'd until the `Order` instance is disposed.

The instance of the object that subscribed to the `Order` event has no knowledge of the reference, and thus is not the cause of the potential memory leak.

Here is a similar question in which Jon Skeet answers.

[Why and How to avoid Event Handler memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526829/why-and-how-to-avoid-event-handler-memory-leaks)

Comment: OK great! So just to be sure, the information stated by the source is completely incorrect and turned the other way around :). Sorry I mentioned discuss, since there is nothing to discuss. It was more about "I'm wondering what the correct explanation is and it's reading this source that's made me confused".

Comment: @user1610325 Yes - I read the entire article itself to be sure there wasn't something missing, but it definitely has it totally backwards, and thus incorrect.  I won't say the rest of the article is totally incorrect, but I would suggest not using it as a reference.  Not sure why this question was put on hold as it's a straight up answerable question that isn't subject to opinion, but I guess it doesn't matter - you got your answer.  Best of luck!