# FrameworkElement's Loaded event - garbage collection

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am using Loaded/Unloaded event of the XAML view.

```
Constructor()
{
   InitializeComponent()
   Loaded += LoadedEvent;
   Unloaded += UnloadedEvent;
}
```

Is it required to unhook these events like Loaded -= LoadedEvent?? or it wont impact in the garbage collection of the View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case View is getting destroyed, you need not to worry about unhooking these event handlers. Garbage collection will take care of this.

For event handling, ***memory leak occurs in case Publisher life time is more than it's subscriber*** *(Publisher holds on to the subscriber instance via Invocation list)*.

***But, in your case publisher and subscriber are same. So, you don't have to worry for unhooking these event handlers.***

You can read more about it here - [**Why and How to avoid Event Handler memory leaks**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526840/632337) ?