# Clarification about variable scope and event handlers

Tags: c#

Please, consider this simple function:

```
public void BeginFade() 
{
    var fade = new DoubleAnimation(0d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    fade.Completed += Fade_Completed;
    grid.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fade);
}
```

The scope of var `fade` is the function `BeginFade` and as far as I understand when the `DoubleAnimation` class has completed its task, the Framework will clear the resources automatically.

Is this correct?

And what about the event handler? When I call more times `BeginFade()` what happens to the event `Completed`?

This example is just to better understand the underlying behaviors. Of course I might declare `fade` as a class member and set the event `Completed` in the constructor...

Comment: has completed its task, the Framework will clear the resources automatically---perhaps not, the clr will also check its references

Comment: It depends if your grid keeps a reference to fade. If it does it can't be cleared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526829/why-and-how-to-avoid-event-handler-memory-leaks

Comment: You passed your `fade` to `BeginAnimation` so in general you now have no idea when it will be garbage collected, because `BeginAnimation` (in theory) might store it in static field or otherwise keep reference to it. As for completed event - and what can happen to it? `fade` is new every time you call `BeginFade` and so is it's `Completed` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your `fade` was passed to `BeginAnimation`, which means that you can not know when it will be disposed of. But I think that in this case, your guess is correct.

With each call to `BeginFade` you create new `fade` object and then `Fade_Completed` event handler subscribes to its `Completed` event. So every one of your `fade` animations has exactly one `Fade_Completed` subscription. That will not stop `fade` objects from being garbage collected if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. But like other comments suggest, it should be better to declare `fade` as class member, to have more control of what happens.

Comment: @Mark there is no reason to declare it as class member, what you are doing now is fine (I assume that is WPF animation).

Comment: Yes, it is! Thanks again.