# Blazor, run non static function when static string change

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, blazor-jsinterop

I'm having a static class with a static string, this string are changed by a Javascript. What is the best way to check for changes of this string in a (non-static) blazor component?

I can have a function run on a timer and let that notify me when a change is made, what other options do I have here?

the function that needs to know if the static string has changed are present in a component that inherits from ComponentBase, if thats any help.

Comment: Observer Pattern?

Comment: How do you "change" the string? Do you call a property setter? Then include the code in that setter, or raise an event?

Comment: Can we see some code? Your component and static string class

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, that is probably the way 2 go, as Amir mentioned below theres the potential problem of memory leaks, guess i'll just have 2 be careful

Comment: @KrisVandermotten the value is set by a js that I have no control over

Comment: @thalacker no, that should not be needed to answer this as its a "best practice" question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to mention that you can invoke an instance .Net method by utilizing Blazor JavaScript interop, have a look at the [following MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#invoke-an-instance-net-method-1).

But to answer your question, as Robert pointed in a comment, using the observer pattern or a simple `Event` can satisfy your need:

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static EventHandler<string> MyPropertyChanged;

    private static string _myProperty;
    public static string MyProperty
    {
        get => _myProperty;
        set
        {
            if (_myProperty != value)
            {
                _myProperty = value;
                MyPropertyChanged?.Invoke(typeof(MyStaticClass), _myProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can subscribe to this event in your non static class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyStaticClass.MyPropertyChanged += MyPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MyPropertyChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Changed value is {e}");
    }
}
```

But the problem with subscribing to a static class event will be the potential memory leak if your `MyClass` instance does not live throughout the app's life cycle, while the static event is. Have a look at [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526840/6803297) explanation on this. You can try unsubscribing from the event when you are done with the `MyClass` instance. Additionally, for a Blazor component, have a look at [Component disposal with IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-disposal-with-idisposable-and-iasyncdisposable-1) where you might be able to unsubscribe in the component disposal. You can also try implementing [Weak Event Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns) to overcome this issue.

Comment: This worked great in a blazor shared layout using a static class to display Toast Messages in dotnet 6. Only add I had to make to get the layout to update was: await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); In the "MyPropertyChanged" method of the class to get the page to actually recognize the update happened. Also had to make the MyPropertyChanged method async void for the await to work. Thanks Amir!

Comment: @Khoward Glad I could help :) Be careful when subscribing to a static class event, as the static class will be holding a pointer to the subscribing method, causing the object to remain in the memory indefinitely. If your subscriber doesn't last throughout your app's life cycle, ensure that you take one of the actions I suggested at the end of the answer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again Amir, I took your Component disposal suggestion and used IDisposable to unsubscribe when the component is disposed to avoid the memory leak scenario!