# Handling Weak Event Patterns in C# to Avoid Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm dealing with a scenario where I have controls (e.g., Labels) dynamically added and removed from a container (e.g., FlowLayoutPanel) in my C# application. These controls are subscribed to events, and I want to make sure that when a control is removed, it doesn't cause a memory leak due to lingering event subscriptions.

I've encountered situations where I cannot easily unsubscribe from events directly

*Edit:*

Here is a code example:

```
private Form form2 = new Form();

public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form2.Icon = this.Icon;
    form2.FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        form2.Hide();
    };
    form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    form2.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    form2.BackColor = Color.White;
    form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    form2.Size = new Size(100, 500);
    FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(200, 1);
    form2.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "hello world";
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
    
    form2.Shown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Parent.Text == "Shape")
        {
            switch (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text)
            {
                case "Sphere":
                    break;
                case "Cuboid":
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text == "Shape")
        {
            switch (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text)
            {
                case "Sphere":
                    break;
                case "Cuboid":
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text == "Plane")
        {}
        else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text == "Camera")
        {
        }
        else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text == "Light")
        {}
        else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Text == "Material")
        {}
        else
        { label.Click += (sender, e) => { //some work }
    };
}
```

Comment: "I've encountered situations where I cannot easily unsubscribe from events directly" why? what are the situation?

Comment: I writed the code based on this situation. While i can re-write this to make it unsubscribale, I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: My original code is too large but i'm now editing it into a samller code and i will edit my question.

Comment: is the problem with anonymous method used for `Click` events for labels? Those are problematic to be removed. You can switch to not use them and you should be good to go with unsubscribing.

Comment: The solution is simple: don't use a lambda as an event handler. You shouldn't have done so in the first place if you wanted to be able to remove the handler. Write a named method and use that as the handler, then you can remove it as easily as you added it.

Comment: That's not the problem. Even with a named method, How can i remove all of click events of a control without having the specific name?

Comment: The most important part of the code is missing here! Show the code you use (or part of it) to remove the controls. This memory leak IS ONLY A PROBLEM if the subscribers are removed and the publisher (the form) outlives them. If the form is destroyed (closed) all subscriptions will be cancelled and there'll be no memory leak. So, show us the code you use to remove the controls, and then I can try to help you to find a way to prevent the leaks if they are really a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of leaking memory with event subscribers only occurs when the publisher outlives the subscriber. It's very well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879531/285678

So, you'll only need to worry if your controls actually are being removed from the form while the form will still "go on"... I that case, these controls should unsubscribe from the `Form` events they hooked up to.

But it seems to me that you don't actually have a problem here:

```
{ label.Click += (sender, e) => { //some work }
```

If this is the `Control` that's actually being "removed" and it doesn't actually subscribe to form events, it is in fact the event **publisher** here. Since it's being destroyed, you actually don't need to remove any of its event's subscribers!

It's important that you show more of the code, to see how you're removing the controls, if they actually hold event subscriptions over the form, or if they are actually the event **publishers**, in which case you don't have a leak.

---

Even though you don't need to clean up the subscribers you could do some clean up on control removal. I've written some code from scratch, holding a `Dictionary<Control, Action>` which I can use to store "cleanup" actions which I only call once when a "label" is removed from the `FlowLayoutPanel`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddControls();
    }

    Dictionary<Control, Action> Cleaners = new Dictionary<Control, Action>();

    void AddControls() {
        FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(200, 1);
        flowLayoutPanel1.ControlRemoved += (s, e) => {
            Cleanup(e.Control);
        };
        Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var label = new Label();
            label.Text = $"Hello World ({i})";
            EventHandler labelClick = (s, e) => {
                // some code;
            };
            label.Click += labelClick;

            // add a cleanup action which can do even more than just event clearing
            // notice that you don't need to clear the "label.click" because label itself is 
            // being removed/destroyed and its the publisher here, not the subscriber
            // but as I don't have access to more of your code I'll do this anyway
            Cleaners.Add(label, () => {
                // the labelClick variable is captured here
                // see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions
                label.Click -= labelClick;
                // your clean up code can do much more here :-) 
            });

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
        }
    }

    void Cleanup(Control control) {
        // calls the clean up action when a control is removed
        if (Cleaners.TryGetValue(control, out Action action)) {
            action();
            Cleaners.Remove(control);
        }
    }
}
```